# Match regex with numeric value and decimal

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match regex to value that is numeric with decimal. Currently I have /^-?[0-9]\d*(.\d+)/ but it does not account for .00 
How would I fix that

Current Valid:

```
1
1.0 
1.33
.00
```

Current Invalid:

```
Alpha Character
```

Comment: Can please post a sample of the desired matches?

Comment: I think you need [`/\A-?\d*\.?\d+\z/`](http://rubular.com/r/YIN40sgxUz). Do you need to match `4.` strings, too?

Comment: Can the match part of a string (e.g., "add 2.1 cups") or must it comprise the entire string?

Comment: are you including something like  : `100,000.00`  or `100.2e9`, ?

Comment: The desired match should take the valid but also 0.00, it does not account for the 0.00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to handle the two possibilities (numbers without a decimal part and numbers without an integer part):

```
/\A-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\z/
#^   ^  ^            ^^     ^---- end of the string
#|   |  |            |'---- without integer part
#|   |  |            '---- OR
#|   |  '---- with an optional decimal part
#|   '---- non-capturing group
#'---- start of the string
```

or make all optional and ensure there's at least one digit:

```
/\A-?+(?=.??\d)\d*\.?\d*\z/
#  ^  ^  ^        ^---- optional dot
#  |  |  '---- optional char (non-greedy)
#  |  '---- lookahead assertion: means "this position is followed by"
#  '---- optional "-" (possessive)
```

Note: I used the non-greedy quantifier `??` only because I believe that numbers with integer part are more frequent, but it can be a false assumption. In this case change it to a greedy quantifier `?`. *(whatever the kind of quantifier you use for the "unknow char" it doesn't matter, this will not change the result.)*

Answer (score 1):

If the first part is optional you can mark it off as such with `(?:...)?:

```
/\A(?:-?[0-9]\d*)?(.\d+)/
```

The `?:` beginning means this is a non-capturing group so it won't interfere with the part you're trying to snag.

Answer (score 1):

What about simple: `/\d*\.?\d*/` ?

Comment: This pattern succeeds for all the strings of the universe. *(because it matches the empty string, since all is optional)*.

Comment: What do you mean?! `\d` will match only digits for example. I agree that it will also match simple `.`, but this is the only exception to what the OP wants, isn't? It does not match `test` for example... I guess that's what you are implying.

Comment: It indeed doesn't match `test` *(since it matches the empty string at the first "t" position)*, but it succeeds with `test`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Have to agree on this one. Good catch (+1)!

Answer (score 1):

Create a regex with the variants you want to match, in this case, 3:

```
N
N.NN
.NN
```

**i.e.:**

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+|\.\d+)
```

[regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN9hK5/4)

Comment: This doesn't catch the case of a number without a decimal point (ex: 1).

Comment: @Awesominator I've updated my answer, thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like `^\-?[0-9\.]+` or `(^\-?[0-9\.]+)`, if you want to capture that specific part of the line only. This looks for any combination of the digits `0` through `9` and a decimal point (`.`), at the beginning of a line with the option of it starting with a dash (`-`).

I also highly recommend the website [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) as a great place to test and play with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach.

```
def match_it(str)
  str if str.gsub(/[\d\.-]/, '').empty? && Float(str) rescue nil
end

match_it "1"     #=> "1" 
match_it "1.0"   #=> "1.0" 
match_it "-1.0"  #=> "-1.0" 
match_it "1.33"  #=> "1.33" 
match_it ".00"   #=> ".00" 
match_it "-.00"  #=> "-.00" 
match_it "1.1e3" #=> nil 
match_it "Hi!"   #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. :

`(^-?[\d+]*[\.\d+]*)`

Just try :)

Comment: At most one decimal point: `"1....."[/^-?[\d+]*[\.\d+]*/] #=> "1....."`. Also, don't you mean `[\d]*`?